# OpenCV Background Subtraction in Python - using a Canon DSLR

Tags: python, image, opencv

I wanted to perform background subtraction using opencv in Python using a Canon T5 1200D DSLR camera's video recording ability. Is this possible? How should I go about it?

I have the code to perform the background subtraction in python using opencv which can be found in many stackoverflow posts but cannot seem to connect to the DSLR and control the video mode.

I succesfully can perform background subtraction on photos pairs controlling the dslr in gphoto2 but am not getting the results I would like, so I figured giving it a shot with opencv's background subtraction functions might be the way to go.

Comment: do you grab a frame, process it (e.g. for background subtraction) and show the results? like [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture)? What video mode?

Comment: @Miki What you linked is C++ code. I will be using python. It is more along the lines of [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html)

Comment: yeah... are you doing that?

Comment: @Miki What you linked is C++ code. I will be using python. It is more along the lines of [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html) - (see BackgroundSubtractorMOG section). By video mode, I mean that I have the DSLR set to video recording mode. No data is actually being collected from the camera (i.e. all data variable are set to None), for this reason I am inferring that the program is not connecting to it properly.

Comment: _No data is actually being collected from the camera_ you should put it in "streaming" mode. Or record the video, save it and process it offline.

Comment: @Miki this is slightly unclear for me. So I cannot control the video recording to start and stop using openCV commands? My end goal is to extract a foreground image of a scene using background subtraction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82842/discussion-between-miki-and-bazzoli92).